# Large fail2ban database, normal?

Tags: fail2ban

The fail2ban database on my server is quite large (420MB).

The fail2ban log is quite busy (there is a "filter" entry every two seconds) but `iptables` shows only a few banned addresses.

dbpurgeage is 86400 seconds (24hours)

Is this size coherent with the activity or is there something going on?

I assume that if I do stop/erase DB/start I will get back to a sensible size, but won't this make the active bans permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just discovered this issue on my own servers. My `dbpurgeage` is also set to the default 24 hours, yet my `fail2ban.sqlite3` grew to 400MB and has 800,000 bans from the last 2 years.

It turns out [fail2ban didn't actually have code to purge the DB until v0.11](https://bugs.debian.org/933749). It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/681bc2ef07ebdf749ccef624d8d598de42b0c6b6). dbpurgeage does nothing before then.

---

To see how many bans are in the DB:

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3 "select count(*) from bans"
```

To see how old your oldest DB entry is:

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3 "select datetime(min(timeofban), 'unixepoch') from bans"
```

To cleanup the DB, for example keep only the last week of data:

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3 "delete from bans where timeofban < strftime('%s', 'now', '-7 days')"
sqlite3 /var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3 "vacuum"
```

The deletion might take several minutes, during which fail2ban will get blocked if it tries to access the database. Perhaps you may want to delete in smaller batches (first everything older than 2 years, then 1 year, etc), to give fail2ban a chance to run in between, and vacuum at the end.

Comment: Excellent answer... my fail2ban DB is now 74K (down from 780M). The discussion you point even includes a script to do the purge using the  F2B config values.